# iOS Downloading and streaming over cellular network limits

Tags: iphone, ios, limit, 3g

I've got question about using cellular network (3G) in my app. I'm interested in streaming video files, downloading them and saving on device over cellular network. Is there any limit for cellular network? And if there's a limit, how big it is?

Comment: There are no general cellular network limits. Those are very specific and operator specific, if they exist. For example, there are operators that limit the number of concurrent network connections - to make things even more confusing, those limits are sometimes only applied to certain contracts but not others of the very same operator. In the end that is exactly what HTTP-Streaming is for. It adapts to the limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in my comment, there are no general operator limitations - still specific limits exist.

However, there is a very clear limit when it comes to progressive download of video content imposed by Apple themselves.

From [Using HTTP Live Streaming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html)

> Requirements for Apps
>
> Warning: iOS apps submitted for distribution in the App Store must
>   conform to these requirements. If your app delivers video over
>   cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or
>   5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP
>   Live Streaming. (Progressive download may be used for smaller clips.)
>
> If your app uses HTTP Live Streaming over cellular networks, you are
>   required to provide at least one stream at 64 Kbps or lower bandwidth
>   (the low-bandwidth stream may be audio-only or audio with a still
>   image).
>
> These requirements apply to iOS apps submitted for distribution in the
>   App Store for use on Apple products. Non-compliant apps may be
>   rejected or removed, at the discretion of Apple.